# Extract the masks values from detectron2 object detection Segmentation and then draw the mask with opencv and calculate the area of that mask?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation, detectron

I want to calculate the area of predicted masks from the output of Detectron2 object detection Segmentation
So when I run inference it returns the dictionary
`outputs = predictor(im)`

`pred_mask,pred_boxes,pred_scores`. When I print the `pred_masks` the values are in binary `(False,True)`

But when i call the visualizer function by sending the predictions it paste all the predicted masks but it shows me (true false ) I don't get it
Here is a coed of visualizer

```
v = Visualizer(im\[:, :, ::-1\],
metadata=grain_metadata,
scale=0.5,
instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW
)
out = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs\["instances"\].to("cpu"))
cv2_imshow(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

This function is in a file

```
(detectron2->utils->visualizer->draw_instance_predictions(predictions)
```

I made some changes in that file in collab like trying to print the masks but it didn't affect at all I comment on the whole file but still the visualizer working can someone tell me how to get the masks values so I will draw on my own using OpenCV.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `pred_masks` values are binary because it is a [binary mask](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/mask.htm#:~:text=A%20mask%20is%20a%20binary,zero%20in%20the%20output%20image.). So, the values you see printed are correct.

Comment: yes i want to get the polygons and draw by my self ?
i dont know how to do this

Answer (score 3):

The values in `pred_masks` values are binary because it contains [binary masks](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/mask.htm#:%7E:text=A%20mask%20is%20a%20binary,zero%20in%20the%20output%20image.).

Referring to the [Detectron2 model output format](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/models.html#model-output-format), you can get the contours of every predicted mask using OpenCV's [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# "outputs" is the inference output in the format described here - https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/models.html#model-output-format

# Extract the contour of each predicted mask and save it in a list
contours = []
for pred_mask in outputs[0]['instances'].pred_masks:
    # pred_mask is of type torch.Tensor, and the values are boolean (True, False)
    # Convert it to a 8-bit numpy array, which can then be used to find contours
    mask = pred_mask.numpy().astype('uint8')
    contour, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    contours.append(contour[0]) # contour is a tuple (OpenCV 4.5.2), so take the first element which is the array of contour points
```

`contours` can then be used to draw the objects using OpenCV's [drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) like below.

```py
# "image" is the original BGR image

image_with_overlaid_predictions = image.copy()

for contour in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(image_with_overlaid_predictions, [contour], -1, (0,255,0), 1)
```